# $useDbConfig for all uses models at once in Controller for CakePHP v2.x.x

Tags: php, database, cakephp, model-view-controller, controller

I am currently writing the separate lines for all the models defined in `Public $uses = array('Lead', 'User', 'Source', ...)` to use the `$useDbConfig` in Controller.

```
$this->Lead->useDbConfig = $newDbConfig['name'];
$this->User->useDbConfig = $newDbConfig['name'];
$this->Source->useDbConfig = $newDbConfig['name'];
```

But i want to set `$useDbConfig` for all `$uses` `->useDbConfig` at once.
With `foreach` loop it isn't seems to achieve. Is there any way  to achieve it?
Cake v2.5.7

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want your Lead, User, *etc.* models to use the alternative db config the way I'd approach this is to create a new AppModel for these models that changes useDbConfig and extends AppModel:-

```
class AltAppModel extends AppModel {

    public $useDbConfig = 'your-alt-db-config';

}
```

Then for your models that require the alternative config extend the new AppModel instead

```
class Lead extends AltAppModel {

}
```

Obviously use a better naming convention than AltAppModel that's more suited to your project. :-)

**Update**

Not sure if this would work or not, but based on your comments you could try something like this:-

```
class AppModel extends Model {

    public function changeDbConfig($config) {

        $this->useDbConfig = $config;

        // Update the belongs to associates
        foreach ($this->belongsTo as &$Model) {        
            $Model->useDbConfig = $config;        
        }
        // Then repeat for hasOne and hasMany...

    }

}
```

Then when you need to dynamically change `$useDbConfig` call:-

```
$this->Lead->changeDbConfig('your-alt-db-config');
```

I'm not 100% sure that this would work though as Cake may not let you update these in this way. Dynamically changing `$useDbConfig` feels a little quirky to me. If you're changing it based on the app setup it would be better to change this in bootstrap.

Comment: Actually i want to give the value to $useDbConfig dynamically. With your solution i can think to create a function which set the value to the class $useDbConfig variable, but its not working for related tables.

Comment: Not sure if this would work or not, but when you dynamically set $useDbConfig you could try running through the associations and setting each model's $useDbConfig. Possibly won't work but worth a try.

Comment: Can you please explain how associations would help? Any code example.

Comment: @Anupal I've updated my answer with a suggestion. Not 100% sure it would work though.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, In your `Controller` you can iterate in the `uses` array, for example:

```
public $uses = ['Lead', 'User', 'Source'];

foreach ($this->uses as $model) {
     $this->{$model}->setDataSource($newDbConfig['name']);
 }
```